# How to fix the function value in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: function, google-sheets

How we can fix the result of the function in Google spreadsheets? For example, I have entered

```
=2*A1;
```

for B1 and what should I do to keep B1 fixed so that it won't be affected by the changes in A1.

The question can be awkward, but I couldn't have found a way to do it.

Answer (score 21):

You can do it by replacing formula with its result:

1. Select cells, which you want to keep value only
2. Dropdown toolbar Edit, choose Copy
3. Dropdown toolbar Edit, choose Paste value only

I hope it's that what you mean

Answer (score 10):

I think this might be the link you are looking for.

Simply write a "$" before the cell or column or whatever you wanna have to fixed.

Example:   $D$4   if you write $D4   you will only get column fixed what I understand.

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/14.3

Comment: The question is about how to make the result be calculated only one time.

Answer (score 0):

The point of functions is so that B1 IS affected by A1.  If you don't want a relationship there, don't use a function.  As far as I know, you will need to just manually type in the value you want, or copy the cell, and right click the cell and click "Paste values only."

Comment: This doesn't help. Lets say I have 10 values in my sheet and I want to sum it up quickly. I would use a sheet function instead of performing that operation somewhere else and entering the final value. what me and OP are looking is some shortcut which changes the dynamic nature of the cell to static.